# Is there a regex filter for removing characters attached to special characters? (@,#)

Tags: python, regex, csv

I got a .csv file of a user's tweets that I intend to feed to a GPT-2 model and I'd like to use a regex filter to remove any replies and hashtags contained within each row. I'm looking for a way to remove elements such as an @ and #, so removing the @ and # as well as the text attached to the symbol using python.

I tried using this as a filter but I'm curious if there's a simpler method:

```
(?:^|_|[^\w&/]+)(?:#|@)([\wÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a LOT simpler, but a few things.

Are you passing this regex to re.sub to rewrite the string?  `Newstring=re.sub(pattern, '',texttorewrite)`  sub will replace the entire match with the second parameter, in this case, nothing.  It will also replace all matches by default.

Your first group seems like it ought to be a negative lookbehind like this

`(?<![\w&/])`

The beginning of string matches in a negative lookbehind. If you need the underscore to be a delimiter replace \w with a-zA-Z0-9.

Then instead of second group just `[@&]` no parens, and lose the parens around your final group.

So to summarize,

```
Newstring = re.sub(r'(?<![\w&/])[@&][\wÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+', '', texttorewrite)
```